# Serialize in Windows Mobile 6.1

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I have an XML document that I am serializing, however it is taking a very long time. Is there a limitation on Windows Mobile 6.1 Pro that causes a serialization to be very slow? I am getting times in the 1-1.5 (s) for a 16Kb String.

Using .NET CF 3.5 Serializing into RAM.

```
serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request_PrintInfo));

"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
        "<Request_TestSale xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">"
        "  <Product>"
        "    <Ref>1</Ref>"
        "    <Name>Product 1</Name>"
        "    <ShortName>P1</ShortName>"
        "    <Abbreviation>P.1</Abbreviation>"
        "    <Id>494a8011-16a0-46ff-980f</Id>"
        "    <Attribs>"
        "      <ConfigAttribute>"
        "        <Name>price</Name>"
        "        <Required>false</Required>"
        "        <ReadOnly>true</ReadOnly>"
        "        <Value>200</Value>"
        "      </ConfigAttribute>"
        "      <ConfigAttribute>"
        "        <Name>Quantity</Name>"
        "        <Required>true</Required>"
        "        <ReadOnly>true</ReadOnly>"
        "        <Value>1</Value>"
        "      </ConfigAttribute>"
        "    </Attribs>"
        "  </Product>"
        "</Request_TestSale>"
```

Comment: And serializing it to where?  RAM?  Flash?

Comment: updates the question apologies.

Comment: Adam, if you could post a little code showing what you are trying to serialize and how you are doing it, one of us might be able to take that and modify that code to work with other techniques (like Ran's XmlTextWriter or josef's (sql or JSON).XML technique.

Comment: @jp2code I have updated the question... any illustration on how to do this faster would be very appreciated.

Comment: @AdamSurfari: That doesn't look like XML. It looks like a string. Are you sure this is the code you are using?

Comment: hum? This is the stream that is passed from the client and then is serialized. It represents the type of object that is created... Is there anything in particular that you are looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but I added an answer anyway. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you mean you're *de*serializing?  You have XML and are creating an object from it?  If so, show us the definition of the class.

Comment: Yes, well both actually I get XML Request turn that into an Object, send it to a DLL with a Command(RequestObject) method that returns a Response Object and I then turn that into XML, it's a ridiculous design, but . I do not have the source for that class it is part of a DLL given to me by a third party.

Answer (score 1):

XmlSerializer is relatively very slow. I would suggest considering using an XmlTextWriter directly to serialize your object.

The code would be more complicated but it will be much more faster and will require much less memory - two considerations that are usually very strong on a mobile device.

Comment: Using xml is always slow. The signal to noise ratio is very bad. There are better alternative solutions to work with structured data (for example sql or JSON).XML is good for data exchange between incompatible systems.

Comment: josef: If Adam posts up any code, I am VERY interested to see how you wrote your (sql or JSON).XML technique.

Comment: @josef: yes, but if for whatever reason you *are* using Xml, then at least you can do it efficiently - without loading the entire data to memory or using reflection to parse it.

Comment: I have updated my question with some code. I am getting very long times... that code is taking 95-105 (ms) to serialize and about the same to Deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I see you have:

```
private void DoNotUnderstandThis() {
  var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Request_PrintInfo));
  string data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
     "<Request_TestSale xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
     "  <Product>" +
     "    <Ref>1</Ref>" +
     "    <Name>Product 1</Name>" +
     "    <ShortName>P1</ShortName>" +
     "    <Abbreviation>P.1</Abbreviation>" +
     "    <Id>494a8011-16a0-46ff-980f</Id>" +
     "    <Attribs>" +
     "      <ConfigAttribute>" +
     "        <Name>price</Name>" +
     "        <Required>false</Required>" +
     "        <ReadOnly>true</ReadOnly>" +
     "        <Value>200</Value>" +
     "      </ConfigAttribute>" +
     "      <ConfigAttribute>" +
     "        <Name>Quantity</Name>" +
     "        <Required>true</Required>" +
     "        <ReadOnly>true</ReadOnly>" +
     "        <Value>1</Value>" +
     "      </ConfigAttribute>" +
     "    </Attribs>" +
     "  </Product>" +
     "</Request_TestSale>";
}
```

I really don't understand how you are getting the string above into an XML document. However, like Ran said, you should look into a `XmlTextWriter`.

Using your string data, I'd write something like this (untested):

```
private const string CRLF = "\r\n";
private const string CRLFTAB = "\r\n\t";
private const string CRLFTABTAB = "\r\n\t\t";
private const string CRLFTABTABTAB = "\r\n\t\t";
private object writeLock = new object();

private void WriteToXml(string filename) {
  lock (writeLock) {
    using (FileStream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)) {
      using (XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
        xw.WriteStartElement("Product"); // writes the root
        {
          xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTAB);
          xw.WriteElementString("Ref", "1");
          xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTAB);
          xw.WriteElementString("Name", "Product 1");
          xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTAB);
          xw.WriteElementString("ShortName", "P1");
          xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTAB);
          xw.WriteElementString("Abbreviation", "P.1");
          xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTAB);
          xw.WriteElementString("Id", "494a8011-16a0-46ff-980f");
          xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTAB);
          xw.WriteStartElement("Attribs");
          {
            xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTAB);
            xw.WriteStartElement("ConfigAttribute");
            {
              xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTABTAB);
              xw.WriteElementString("Name", "price");
              xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTABTAB);
              xw.WriteElementString("Required", "false");
              xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTABTAB);
              xw.WriteElementString("ReadOnly", "true");
              xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTABTAB);
              xw.WriteElementString("Value", "200");
              xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTABTAB);
            }
            xw.WriteEndElement(); // Write the close tag for the ConfigAttribute element
            xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTAB);
            xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTAB);
            xw.WriteStartElement("ConfigAttribute");
            {
              xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTABTAB);
              xw.WriteElementString("Name", "Quantity");
              xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTABTAB);
              xw.WriteElementString("Required", "true");
              xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTABTAB);
              xw.WriteElementString("ReadOnly", "true");
              xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTABTAB);
              xw.WriteElementString("Value", "1");
              xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTABTAB);
            }
            xw.WriteEndElement(); // Write the close tag for the ConfigAttribute element
            xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLFTABTAB);
          }
          xw.WriteEndElement(); // Write the close tag for the Attribs element
          xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLF);
        }
        xw.WriteEndElement(); // Write the close tag for the root element
        xw.WriteWhitespace(CRLF);
        xw.Flush();
        xw.Close();
      }
      stream.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully, this will get you somewhere. I'm not even sure if that's what you are looking for, though.